# Magento 2 which directories to be shared on multiple magento servers via load balancer?

Tags: nginx, magento, magento2, varnish

consider 3 servers

1. nginx for SSL and Varnish for cache(with 2 httpd(magento) backends)
2. httpd(magento) server + redis (session storage)
3. httpd + DB

> "between the httpd(magento) servers - which directories should be
>   shared to make magento completely functional? "

Answer (score 1):

From: https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/deploy/cloud-deployment-process.html

- `app/etc/`
- `pub/media/`
- `var/`, but not `var/log`

Magento Cloud also shares `pub/static`, but this is only necessary if you do on-server static content deploy (not recommended). If you're following [pipeline deployment](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/deployment/) recommendations, your static content would be precompiled and deployed into each node individually.

Comment: how would you solve this usecase: when creating website sitemap, if administrator configures following: filename=sitemap.xml and path=/. Sitemap is generated directly into to pub/ directory - pub/sitemap.xml. And this file should be accessible by nginx and served as static content. But problem is with pub/static, which is generated during pipeline deployment, this folder needs to be replaced. 
This problem is also with var/view_preprocessed

Any solutions?